# ExtJS 4 - How to add background colors to columns of a grid?

Tags: extjs, background, grid, background-color

I have a *grid* in which I need to provide different *background colors* to various columns.

These column colors should also not be overwritten by the `mouse-over` color.

I have tried using `cls` and `tdCls` but no luck.

Could anyone guide at how this could be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have been able to find a solution for this. I am creating a renderer function for each column and I am setting the metadata in it like:

    renderer : function(value, metadata, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store){
  //metadata.tdCls = 'lookUpClass';
  metadata.style = 'background:#EBEBF5';
  return value;
 }

When using tdCls, its applying color to alternate rows and not each one.

Hope this is the way of achieving background-color and may be this helps someone. If any better way, please share.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NetEmp is right here, you want a renderer and you want to use the direct 'style' method or I did it below using the following:

```
function greyRenderer(lpValue, opMeta, opData) 
{

    if (opData.data["Condition"] == 0) {
        opMeta.attr = "style='color: #aaa';";
    }

    lpValue = Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(lpValue); 
    return lpValue;
}
```

Note here I check the value on the row in a particular field and then apply the colour to the foreground text and html encode the output, you can obviously just switch things to your specific requirements.

Comment: Why not use the opMeta.style property?

Comment: As i mentioned in the answer, you could use the style method, but that renderer is just one I had kicking about. We weren't using ExtJS4 at the time and I believe 'attr' was the only way to apply style - http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.Column-property-renderer

Answer (score 4):

add this to whatever column you want to change color

```
renderer:function(value,metaData){
    metaData.style="background-color:#EAA8A8";
    return value;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a renderer for this.  What's happening is that ExtJS's zebra striping style (`x-grid-row-alt`) and mouse over style take precedence over the style you defined in `tdCls`.  Add `!important` to the background color and it'll work.  For example:

```
.my-column-style {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```