# change color of rows in grid in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, grid, gridpanel

How to get the Backgroud or text colour of first five rows to be different from the next five rows.
For example, First 5 Yellow,5 Orange,5 Yellow,5 Orange,and so on..

I added following listener for the grid

```
listeners: {
    viewready: function(g) {
        g.getView().getRow(1).style.color="#f30";
    }
}
```

I've used this to get the contents in second line in red.But it's not working for me.

Comment: Code of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a custom GridView getRowClass method:

```
var mygrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
   viewConfig: {
      getRowClass: function(record, index, rowParams)
      {
         return (Math.floor(index / 5.0) % 2 == 0) ? 'rowClass1' : 'rowClass2';
      }
   }
})
```

Then define in your page or in your css the custom row style classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need this http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer

example

[ExtJS 4 - How to add background colors to columns of a grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444182/extjs-4-how-to-add-background-colors-to-columns-of-a-grid)