# How to add background-color for particular column in Grid using ext-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, extjs

I am trying to add background color for 2 column in grid table how can i do that?
Is there any property that I can configure?

Here I have created 2 tables and attached to one.

Please find my code below-

```
var ALIASGRID = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
                store : ALIASGRIDStore,
                stripeRows : true,
                hideHeaders : true,
                id : "ALIASGRID",
                region : 'center',
                clicksToEdit : 1,
                autoHeight : true,
                viewConfig : {
                    markDirty : false
                },
                columnLines : true,
                columns : [ {
                    id : 'Test',
                    header : 'Test',
                    dataIndex : 'Test',
                    width : 30,
                    editor: {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
         

           triggers: {
                        search: {
                            cls: 'x-fa fa-search',
                            handler: function (field, trigger, eOpts) {}
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    renderer : renderTooltipAndId
                }],
                listeners : {
                    beforeedit : function(grid) {
                        if (!attributeMgrEnabled) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        // console.log(grid);
                    }
                }
            });
            
var ALIASFOOTER = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
                enableHdMenu : false,
                id : 'ALIASFOOTER',
                height : 19,
                store : ALIASFOOTERStore,
                columns : [ {
                    id : 'Test',
                    header : 'Testing.',
                    resizable : false,
                    width : 30
                }]});           
                
                
// Table that shows empty rows & a footer
            var layoutTable1 = new Ext.Panel({
                width : 470,
                items : [ ALIASGRID, ALIASFOOTER ],
                renderTo : 'AliasTable'
            });
```

I have tried to use bodyStyle: 'background-color: #ff0000; property but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Use can use a custom `renderer` on the column and specify the style using `metaData.tdStyle`:

```
columns: [{
    text: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    renderer: function (value, metaData) {
        metaData.tdStyle = 'background-color: red;';
        return value;
    },
}],
```

Comment: Hi Peter, I was trying using tdCls property but somehow it is not working and for rendering I have common function. Do we have any simple property to do this like readOnly

Comment: How did you try `tdCls`? The example I gave with `tdStyle` does not work for you?